# python spacing issue when printing color to console

Tags: python, console

Im trying to print colored headers to the console but it seems to be messing with the spacing.  Why does it ignore the spacing?

```
yellow = lambda text: '\033[0;33m' + text + '\033[0m'
print(f"{yellow('Header1'):<15} {'Header2':<15} Header2")
```

Output:

```
Header1 Header2         Header2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the padding you added for the yellow color. Here's what the format string is converted to on line 2:

## Initial version

```
print(f"{yellow('Header1'):<15} {'Header2':<15} Header2")
```

## After yellow('Header1') is evaluated

```
print(f"{'\033[0;33mHeader1\033[0m':<15} {'Header2':<15} Header2")
```

You can see that the length is over 15 characters long. Once the statement is printed, your console will convert the special characters and change `Header1` to yellow text. To fix the issue, you can add the yellow padding outside of the `{'Header1':<15}` format.

Something like this could work:

```
print(yellow(f'{'Header1':<15}') + f' {'Header2':<15} Header2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it uses the text returned from the lambda function to count the string length:

**In:**

```
len(yellow('Header1'))
```

**Out:**

```
18
```

Apparently the length to add the spaces is evaluated before the interpretation of the character as color information. Which I think makes sense because the color is probably only interpreted later by the `sys.stdout`.

If you do the following, for instance, you get some spaces back:

**In:**

```
yellow = lambda text: '\033[0;33m' + text + '\033[0m'^M
print(f"{yellow('Header1'):<20} {'Header2':<15} Header2")
```

**Out:**

```
Header1   Header2         Header2
```